# Bengali/Indic font connected letters rendering issue

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, firefox, chrome

I'm having some issue on **Linux Mint 17.2** where Bengali/Bangla font's connected letters are not rendering well while visiting duckduckgo.com. This is how they appear -

[image]

While they should appear like this -

[image]

notice the connected letters like স্ব and ন্য.

The second screenshot is when I change their font-family to `monospace`. But they dont render properly if they are not monospaced. They render properly on OSX for some reason. And another odd thing is that the connected letters appear well when I visit this wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bangla_script_display_help

I'm inclined to believe that there is some issue with the font duckduckgo uses - Proxima Nova. But I cannot be sure as they work fine on OSX. I'm totally confused. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a *lot* of searching, I found [this blog](http://ubuntu-newbie2pro.blogspot.in/2014/03/solve-bangla-font-rendering-problem-in.html) post that suggested that I delete the `FreeFont` font from my system. So I removed this directory `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont`. Now the Bengali letters are rendering properly. I'm not exactly sure why. If you know why, please comment and let me know. Thanks.