# How to fix broken bengali font in linux

Tags: firefox, chrome, fonts

I've installed fresh mx linux. this is my system info:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.10.0-17-amd64 [5.10.136-1] x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-17-amd64 
           root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm 4.16.1 vt: 7 
           dm: LightDM 1.26.0 Distro: MX-21.2_x64 Wildflower August 28  2022 
           base: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

When I open facebook in firefox or chrome, bangla fonts are somewhat broken. Below is a screenshot:
[image: broken bengali text]

As you can see some of the words are not rendered properly.

Steps I've taken to solve this issue:

- I've installed `fonts-noto-core`
- I've installed `fonts-noto-ui-core`

How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't read Bengali, so I don't see which parts are broken. Guess: It might be ligatures (two characters that together need to be rendered differently). Obvious things to try are (1) install other fonts that have Bengali characters, (2) force firefox to use those fonts so you can see if it works better or not, (3) if no available fonts work satisfactorily, install something like fontforge, fix the fonts, submit a patch upstream.

Comment: 1) I don't know what other fonts I need to install besides the one I already did. according to google they should cover all ligatures and it is found to be true in Android devices.

2) I don't want to force firefox/chrome to fix this, because this is an os related issue. I don't want to change font for all text editors and browsers.

3) can you give details about this?

Thanks @dirkt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem that was causing this issue. I removed `FreeSans`and `FreeSerif` family fonts and the issue was fixed.

**Solution:**

```
# install required fonts
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-core
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-ui-core

# remove the conflicting fonts
sudo rm -f /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans*
sudo rm -f /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif*

# update font cache
fc-cache -f -v
```

Helpful References:
[bengali-indic-font-connected-letters-rendering-issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235218/bengali-indic-font-connected-letters-rendering-issue?rq=1)
[bangla-font-rendering-problem](http://ubuntu-newbie2pro.blogspot.com/2014/03/solve-bangla-font-rendering-problem-in.html)

Comment: That takes care of "force Firefox to use those fonts" - removing conflicting fonts is one way to deal with that. So you **did** force Firefox to do it. And the reason for the problem was that it didn't use those fonts before.

Comment: yes, in that sense you're notion is correct. thanks @dirkt